# Crontab start node application with forever in production mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, forever

I have a node.js application that I start using forever like so:

```
NODE_ENV=production forever start index.js
```

I've also worked out how to setup crontab to automatically start the forever command for this application on server reboot:

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/forever start /path/to/my/app/index.js
```

The only problem here is the node environment. How do I add the production environment to the crontab command?

Comment: I've never seen a crontab like that. What cron daemon are you using that provides a `@reboot` command?

Comment: @Sukima http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/

Comment: Huh, I didn't know that command. Learned something new, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set just one environment variable, you could use the export command right before the forever command.

```
@reboot export NODE_ENV=production; /usr/local/bin/forever start /path/to/my/app/index.js
```

For more than one variable Sukima's method is better.

Comment: Excellent thanks. It's just the one variable I need so I'll try this. Is the semi-colon required after the `NODE_ENV=production`?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to execute a special command with variables etc. in a crontab it's easier to write a simple shell script and call that script from the crontab:

```
#!/bin/bash
export NODE_ENV=production
/usr/local/bin/forever start /path/to/my/app/index.js
```

Make it executable: `chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/start_my_app.sh`

Then in your crontab:

```
@reboot /usr/local/bin/start_my_app.sh
```